# Is there any way to write this c statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`int a = 10;`

`int b = -a++;`

Is there any way to write this expression in python?
If any to write this in python then how to write it in python?

Comment: First, why do you need to do this in a single line? Second, are you interested in a single _statement_ (declarations in C, and assignments in Python, are both statements), or a single _expression_ (assignments and `++` in C are expressions, but their closest equivalents are statements in Python)?

Answer (score 3):

There is no `++` operator in Python so you would need to use multiple statements

```
a = 10
b = -a
a += 1
```

It's not actually that big a deal because `b = -a++` is a confusing thing to write anyway.

Comment: is this statement cannot be written in single statement.

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey You can write `b, a = -a, a+1`, which I think is closer to the intention of your C code. and also more readable than your C code.

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey But the bigger question is: why do you need this to be a single statement in the first place?

Comment: @abarnert this question has appeared in C, So i want its python single line statement.

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey I don't know what you mean by that. But, as a general rule, if you're trying to translate C code to Python (or Python code to Java, or Ruby code to Haskell, or whatever) by translating line by line, you're going to end up with very bad Python (or Java or Haskell or whatever) code that isn't readily understandable to people who know either C or Python.

Comment: Okay understand @abarnert.

Answer (score 2):

you can try (as user [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) also points out)

```
a = 10
b, a = -a, a+1
```

to write it in 1 line. and the code is much more clear in its intent

Comment: @PM2Ring Not in any important way, unless the namespace `a` and `b` live in is something unusual. (That being said, the reason I suggested `b, a = -a, a+1` in a comment on Nick Chapman's answer is that it makes the fact that the relevant ordering is equivalent to the C code a bit more obvious.)

Comment: @abarnert, i didn't notice your comment until now. its a small difference but I think you are right in your statement being _truer_ to the c version on the surface.

Comment: Actually, the closest equivalent to the C code is probably be something like `_a = copy.copy(a); a += 1; b = -_a; del _a`, which _does_ assign `a` before `b`. But you'd never write that in Python. And it's still not very close to the C code, because it's creating new int objects all over the place rather than mutating the values of int slots, etc., so…